# Laravel 8 - XDebugger not working on breakpoint

Tags: php, laravel, xdebug, vscode-debugger

I am trying to get my xdebugger to work, I am using php artisan serve so I don't know if thats the issue.

launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 8000
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 0,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
            ],
            "env": {
                "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
                "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
                "-S",
                "localhost:0"
            ],
            "program": "",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "port": 8000,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
                "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
                "action": "openExternally"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I added different things on my php.ini like changin the port

```
 [xDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable =1
xdebug.remote_autostart =1

zend_extension = "D:\Software\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_port = 8000
xdebug.client_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.log = "D:\log\xdebug.log"
xdebug.idekey = VSCODE
```

this is my xdebug.log
I am using this URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/brand/all if that helps.

This is my breakpoint.
[image]

I dont know what am I doing wrong.

xdebug.log

```
[2704] Log opened at 2022-02-25 11:48:26.092657
[2704] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:8000.
[2704] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: 127.0.0.1:8000 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). :-)
[2704] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="dbgp://stdin" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.4.23" protocol_version="1.0" appid="2704" idekey="VSCODE"><engine version="3.1.3"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2022 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[5008] Log opened at 2022-02-25 11:48:26.345514
[5008] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:8000.
[5008] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: 127.0.0.1:8000 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). :-)
[5008] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="dbgp://stdin" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.4.23" protocol_version="1.0" appid="5008" idekey="VSCODE"><engine version="3.1.3"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2022 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[632] Log opened at 2022-02-25 11:48:26.351843
[632] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:8000.
[632] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: 127.0.0.1:8000 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). :-)
[632] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="dbgp://stdin" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.4.23" protocol_version="1.0" appid="632" idekey="VSCODE"><engine version="3.1.3"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2022 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[2704] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[2704] Log closed at 2022-02-25 11:48:26.804345

[632] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[632] Log closed at 2022-02-25 11:48:27.031764

[5008] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[5008] Log closed at 2022-02-25 11:48:27.054677
```

When i change it back to port 9003 (the php.ini and launch.json) this is the log

```
[13972] Log opened at 2022-02-25 11:57:26.489494
[13972] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9003.
[11080] Log opened at 2022-02-25 11:57:26.489363
[11080] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9003.
[13972] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: 127.0.0.1:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). :-)
[13972] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="dbgp://stdin" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.4.23" protocol_version="1.0" appid="13972" idekey="VSCODE"><engine version="3.1.3"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2022 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[13972] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 1 -n resolved_breakpoints -v 1
[13972] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="resolved_breakpoints" success="1"></response>

[11080] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: 127.0.0.1:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). :-)
[11080] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="dbgp://stdin" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.4.23" protocol_version="1.0" appid="11080" idekey="VSCODE"><engine version="3.1.3"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2022 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[13972] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 2 -n notify_ok -v 1
[13972] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="notify_ok" success="1"></response>

[11080] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 1 -n resolved_breakpoints -v 1
[11080] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="resolved_breakpoints" success="1"></response>

[13972] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 3 -n extended_properties -v 1
[13972] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="extended_properties" success="1"></response>

[11080] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 2 -n notify_ok -v 1
[11080] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="notify_ok" success="1"></response>

[13972] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 4 -t line -f file:///d:/Software/xampp/htdocs/Laravel8/basic/app/Http/Controllers/BrandController.php -n 22
[11080] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 3 -n extended_properties -v 1
[11080] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="extended_properties" success="1"></response>

[13972] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="4" id="139720001" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[11080] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 4 -t line -f file:///d:/Software/xampp/htdocs/Laravel8/basic/app/Http/Controllers/BrandController.php -n 22
[11080] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="4" id="110800001" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[13972] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 5 -t line -f file:///d:/Software/xampp/htdocs/Laravel8/basic/app/Http/Controllers/BrandController.php -n 48
[13972] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="5" id="139720002" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[11080] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 5 -t line -f file:///d:/Software/xampp/htdocs/Laravel8/basic/app/Http/Controllers/BrandController.php -n 48
[11080] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="5" id="110800002" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[13972] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 6 -t line -f file:///d:/Software/xampp/htdocs/Laravel8/basic/app/Http/Controllers/BrandController.php -n 59
[13972] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="6" id="139720003" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[11080] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 6 -t line -f file:///d:/Software/xampp/htdocs/Laravel8/basic/app/Http/Controllers/BrandController.php -n 59
[11080] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="6" id="110800003" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[13972] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 7 -t line -f file:///d:/Software/xampp/htdocs/Laravel8/basic/app/Http/Controllers/BrandController.php -n 70
[13972] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="7" id="139720004" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[11080] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 7 -t line -f file:///d:/Software/xampp/htdocs/Laravel8/basic/app/Http/Controllers/BrandController.php -n 70
[11080] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="7" id="110800004" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[13972] [Step Debug] <- run -i 8
[11080] [Step Debug] <- run -i 8
[13972] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="8" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[13972] [Step Debug] <- stop -i 9
[13972] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stop" transaction_id="9" status="stopped" reason="ok"></response>

[13972] Log closed at 2022-02-25 11:57:27.218598

[11080] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="8" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[11080] [Step Debug] <- stop -i 9
[11080] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stop" transaction_id="9" status="stopped" reason="ok"></response>

[11080] Log closed at 2022-02-25 11:57:27.253455
```

Comment: @RiggsFolly i dont know if this helps, but the filename is php_xdebug-3.1.3-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll

Comment: I see its V3, default port is 9003, put it back to that. Looks like you are trying to run the server and XDEBUG on the same port, that wont run

Comment: @RiggsFolly i just changed it back, still doesnt work. I updated the question with the xdebug.log

Comment: The question is really, why do you get this? `fileuri="dbgp://stdin"` — that's not a normal file path.

Comment: Refer similar solution (for PHPStorm) https://stackoverflow.com/a/67489462/3140741